# Are there any benefits (or disadvantages) to using the BLOB datatype to store hex data?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am planning to store MAC addresses in an SQLite database. As you may know, MAC addresses consist of hexadecimal digits. I was wondering if there is any benefit (or detriment) to storing these as BLOB datatype. I will be performing SELECT statements with a WHERE clause on this hex column, so I plan to create an index on that column. My platform is Android, and I want to optimize for these select queries. I don't mind expending some extra resources during the insert. Is it better then just to store the data as strings? Another alternative might be to convert the hex MAC address to an integer and store it that way. Any hints on what might give the best performance in the subsequent SELECT queries?